# ROS Logging Display Node Name

Tags: ros, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm very sorry if this is a repeat question, but I'm using robot_upstart which dumps all logging output into the single file /var/log/upstart/foo.log. This makes it really hard to tell which node is talking. I'm currently getting the generic error "Failed to open port" and I'm not sure how to figure out where this message is coming from.

Is there a way to get ROS logging to display to node name?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258929/ros-logging-display-node-name/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [console output formatting](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting). You can set that one time on the command line or add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. For `robot_upstart` you might have to add it in a separate spot or make sure you are using the `.bashrc` of the appropriate user. To get the node name, log level, time and message you could have something like:

```
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='[${severity}] - ${node}: [${time}] ${message}'
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7